# Bulma CSS & child angular component

Tags: angular, bulma

I decide to convert my plain html section into a component and everything works fine but the the child component can not have the reference that it is inside of the reference of *columns*.

**Here is my code where everything works fine:**

```
<div class="columns">
  <div class="column is-4">
    Fruits:
  </div>
  <div class="column is-2">apple</div>
  <div class="column is-2">orange</div>
  <div class="column is-2">pineapple</div>
  <div class="column is-2">banana</div>
</div>
```

But I decided to convert some of the html in a component

**like:**

```
<div class="columns">
  <div class="column is-4">
    Fruits
  </div>
  <app-fruits>
    <div class="column is-2" *ngFor="let fruit of Fruits">
      {{fruit}}
    </div>
  <app-fruits>
</div>
```

I did the *encapsulation none* for *app-fruits*, but is not working, my columns of 2 are not aligned as before. Any help?

Comment: Have you tried making app-fruits `display: contents`?

Comment: @Mendy it doesn't work in IE11+ :(

Comment: If you need to support IE then I cant think of a solution, since column must be a direct child from columns. Sorry for that.

Comment: Also doesn't work when you have a setup like this: <app-fruit class="column is-2" *ngFor="let fruit of Fruits" [fruit]="fruit">

Answer (score 1):

The `.column` element must be a direct child of `.columns` for it to work. Same problem can happen when working with tables.

Here's some solutions that could apply.

#### Use ngFor on `<div>`

You could try to use a ngFor on a div element, and passing the fruit variable to a Fruit component that as a [@Input](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#pass-data-from-parent-to-child-with-input-binding) decorator for the fruit.

```
<div class="columns">
  <div class="column is-4">
    Fruits
  </div>
  <div class="column is-2" *ngFor="let fruit of Fruits">
      <app-fruit-single [fruit]="fruit"></app-fruit-single>
  </div>
</div>
```

#### Try messing with ng-container or custom selector (not advised)

In a Fruit component, you could use a bracketed *attribute selector*, meaning you could put the component in any html tag, as an attribute. This is not advised, [as you can check on the style guide](https://angular.io/guide/styleguide#style-05-03).

```
@Component({
    selector: '[app-fruit-element]',
    ...
})
```

You could then try to use that with [ng-container](https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives#group-sibling-elements-with-ng-container), but you would probably run into issues when creating a component without a DOM element.

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let fruit of fruits" [fruit]="fruit" app-fruit-element></ng-container>
```